# Handling DeadlineTimeoutException or ConnectionClosedException in Apache Http Async client

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-httpclient-5.x, apache-httpasyncclient

I am adding a Sink (RichSinkFunction) to an Apache Flink project running on AWS Managed Flink that sends data to a Http webservice via REST calls (Http POST).

To improve performance I am using the Apache Http client (org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5 v 5.3.1).

Here is the RichSinkFunction.open() method where I create the client. I only use a keep alive strategy of 30 sec and all other settings are default:

```
public void open(Configuration parameters) {
            CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.custom().
                .setKeepAliveStrategy((httpResponse, httpContext) -> TimeValue.of(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .build();
client.start();
}
```

Here is the RichSinkFunction.invoke() function where I call the Http Post request:

```
   SimpleHttpRequest simpleHttpRequest 
     = SimpleRequestBuilder.post(endPoint).setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader).build();
   simpleHttpRequest.setBody(JSON_content, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
   simpleHttpRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   simpleHttpRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
   httpClient.execute(simpleHttpRequest, new FutureCallback<SimpleHttpResponse>() {
     //Callback methods implemented here
   });
```

I see that when there are number of Http updates are very high (I cannot find the exact threshold), and when the REST end point response time is slow, I get a lot of DeadlineTimeoutException.

```
org.apache.hc.core5.util.DeadlineTimeoutException: Deadline: 2024-03-09T12:40:32.438+0000, -199656424 MILLISECONDS overdue
at org.apache.hc.core5.util.DeadlineTimeoutException.from(DeadlineTimeoutException.java:49)
at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool.processPendingRequest(StrictConnPool.java:323)
at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool.processNextPendingRequest(StrictConnPool.java:304)
at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool.release(StrictConnPool.java:266)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.nio.PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager.release(PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager.java:410)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.InternalHttpAsyncExecRuntime.discardEndpoint(InternalHttpAsyncExecRuntime.java:147)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.InternalHttpAsyncExecRuntime.discardEndpoint(InternalHttpAsyncExecRuntime.java:170)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.InternalAbstractHttpAsyncClient$2.failed(InternalAbstractHttpAsyncClient.java:346)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.AsyncRedirectExec$1.failed(AsyncRedirectExec.java:248)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.AsyncHttpRequestRetryExec$1.failed(AsyncHttpRequestRetryExec.java:197)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.AsyncProtocolExec$1.failed(AsyncProtocolExec.java:295)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.HttpAsyncMainClientExec$1.failed(HttpAsyncMainClientExec.java:131)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.ClientH2StreamHandler.failed(ClientH2StreamHandler.java:253)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.AbstractH2StreamMultiplexer$H2Stream.reset(AbstractH2StreamMultiplexer.java:1668)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.AbstractH2StreamMultiplexer$H2Stream.cancel(AbstractH2StreamMultiplexer.java:1693)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.AbstractH2StreamMultiplexer.onDisconnect(AbstractH2StreamMultiplexer.java:575)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.AbstractH2IOEventHandler.disconnected(AbstractH2IOEventHandler.java:96)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.ClientH2IOEventHandler.disconnected(ClientH2IOEventHandler.java:39)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession$1.disconnected(SSLIOSession.java:247)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalDataChannel.disconnected(InternalDataChannel.java:204)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.processClosedSessions(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:231)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.doTerminate(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:106)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.execute(AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.java:93)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.IOReactorWorker.run(IOReactorWorker.java:44)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n
```

Since this Sink's HTTP update is critical how can I configure this client in a way that it pools requests, waits for each request to complete, without dropping it and can handle high throughput (about 100K messages sent in parallel)?

**Update: Approach 2:**

I wanted to simplify the Client and try this without a keep alive strategy.

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = 
    HttpAsyncClients.custom().build();
    client.start();
```

I am seeing smaller number of errors, but I still see this `ConnectionClosedException` exception now:

```
    org.apache.hc.core5.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.AbstractH2StreamMultiplexer.onDisconnect(AbstractH2StreamMultiplexer.java:581)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.AbstractH2IOEventHandler.disconnected(AbstractH2IOEventHandler.java:96)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.ClientH2IOEventHandler.disconnected(ClientH2IOEventHandler.java:39)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession$1.disconnected(SSLIOSession.java:247)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalDataChannel.disconnected(InternalDataChannel.java:204)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.processClosedSessions(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:231)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.doExecute(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:133)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.execute(AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.java:86)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.IOReactorWorker.run(IOReactorWorker.java:44)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would be a good use-case for Flink's available [Asynchronous I/O API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/) which is fault-tolerant, supports custom retry-strategies, etc. via a `RichAsyncFunction`.

Alternatively if your endpoint could handle extremely large requests similar to what you indicated (~100k messages), you could consider implementing your own queue in a stateful function to support your bulk scenario and your eviction strategy (either via a timer or with some defined threshold such as 10k requests).

Comment: Thanks @rion-williams . Even if I use Async I/O, I still need to use the HttpClient and address this connection issue. Also, I need this http update to be sent as live as as possible.